# How to terminate remotely called "tail -f" when connection is closed?

Tags: ssh, terminal, process, signals

I just noticed that if I execute `ssh user@remote_host tail -f /some/file` , then `tail -f /some/file` keeps running on the remote_host even if ssh connection is closed!

So, after several connects and disconnects, number of running `tail -f /some/file` grows. How to actually terminate `tail -f` when ssh connection is closed?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

In

```
ssh host tail -f file
```

The `ssh` client connects to the `sshd` server on `host` over a TCP connection. `sshd` runs `tail -f` with its stdout redirected to a pipe. `sshd` reads what's coming from the other end of the pipe and encapsulates it in the sshd protocol to send to the `ssh` client. (with `rshd`, `tail` stdout would have been the socket directly, but `sshd` adds encryption and is able to multiplex several streams (like for port/agent/X11/tunnel redirection, stderr) on a single TCP connection so has to resort to pipes).

When you press CTRL-C, a SIGINT is sent to the `ssh` client. That causes `ssh` to die. Upon dying the TCP connection is closed. And therefore, on `host`, `sshd` dies as well. `tail` is not killed, but its stdout is now a pipe with no reader at the other end. So, the next time it writes something to its stdout, it will receive a SIGPIPE and die (though recent versions of GNU `tail` monitor for their stdout becoming a broken pipe and exit straight away in that case, see also [this answer to a related question](/a/736865) for how to detect broken pipes).

In:

```
ssh -t host 'tail -f file'
```

It's the same thing except that instead of being with a pipe, the communication between `sshd` and `tail` is via a pseudo-terminal. `tail`'s stdout is a slave pseudo-terminal (like `/dev/pts/12`) and whatever `tail` write there is `read` on the master side (possibly modified by the tty line discipline) by `sshd` and sent encapsulated to the `ssh` client.

On the client side, with `-t`, `ssh` puts the terminal in `raw` mode. In particular, that disables the terminal canonical mode and terminal signal handling.

So, when you press <kbd>Ctrl+C</kbd>, instead of the client's terminal line discipline sending  a SIGINT to the `ssh` job, that just sends the `^C` character over the connection to `sshd` and `sshd` writes that `^C` to the master side of the remote terminal. And the line discipline of the remote terminal sends a `SIGINT` to `tail`. `tail` then dies, and `sshd` exits and closes the connection and `ssh` terminates (if it's not otherwise still busy with port forwardings or other).

Also, with `-t`, if the `ssh` client dies (for instance if you enter `~.`), the connection is closed and `sshd` dies. As a result, a SIGHUP will be sent to `tail`.

Now, beware that using `-t` has side effects. For instance, with the default terminal settings, `\n` characters are converted to `\r\n` and more things may happen depending on the remote system, so you may want to issue a `stty -opost` (to disable output post-processing) on the remote host if that output is not intended for a terminal:

```
$ ssh  localhost 'echo x' | hd
00000000  78 0a                                             |x.|
00000002
$ ssh -t localhost 'echo x' | hd
00000000  78 0d 0a                                          |x..|
00000003
$ ssh -t localhost 'stty -opost; echo x' | hd
00000000  78 0a                                             |x.|
00000002
```

Another drawback of using `-t`/`-tt` is that stdout and stderr are not differentiated on the client. Both the stdout and stderr of the remote command will be written to the `ssh` client's stdout:

```
$ ssh localhost ls /x  | wc -l
ls: cannot access /x: No such file or directory
0
$ ssh -t localhost ls /x | wc -l
1
```

Comment: Thank you very much for such a detailed explanation! I wish I could accept two answers..

Comment: "with `-t`, if the `ssh` client dies (for instance if you enter `~.`)" What is `~.` again?

Comment: @x-yuri, `~.` is the escape sequence you enter to disconnect the client. See `man ssh` for details.

Answer (score 11):

You need terminal allocation on the remote side:

```
ssh -t user@remote_host tail -f /some/file
```

or even

```
ssh -tt user@remote_host tail -f /some/file
```

Comment: Thanks, both `-t` or `-tt` works. But I still can't understand real reason of this: say, when I call shell remotely and close the connection, shell is terminated. But `tail -f` is not. Of course I have already read about `-t` option in `man ssh`, but it didn't help much. It seems I don't understand some generics, and I'd be happy if you suggest some docs to read about it, or probably explain it yourself. Thanks!

Comment: @DmitryFrank My understanding is this: If the connection breaks then `sshd` sends a `SIGHUP`. But where no terminal is there can be no terminal connection hangup...

Comment: Thanks, I will read about `SIGHUP` and other signals, still know almost nothing about it.

Comment: fyi: I just tried to run `tail -f`, then I've opened `htop` and sent `SIGHUP` to it (by pressing `F9` -> `1` -> `Enter`), and `tail -f` is terminated! So, reason should be some different..

Comment: @DmitryFrank You have misunderstood the problem. The problem is **not** that `tail` would not react to `SIGHUP`. The problem is that `SIGHUP` is **not sent` to `tail` without a pseudo terminal. You can see that by attaching `strace` to `tail` in both cases.