# How to stop program of non-interactive SSH call without pseudo-terminal

Tags: shell-script, ssh, scripting, signals, pseudoterminal

Let's say I start a program with a non-interactive SSH call (without pseudo-terminal) and exit the session via <kbd>CTRL</kbd><kbd>C</kbd>:

```
$ ssh user@server -- sleep 123
^C
```

This way, the program, in this case `sleep 123` for example, is still running on `server`, even after the SSH session was terminated:

```
$ ssh user@server -- ps -ef | grep "sleep 123"
user     12430       1  0 19:28 ?        00:00:00 sleep 123
```

I am aware of `ssh`'s `-t` option to have SIGINT sent to the remote `sleep` instead of the local `ssh`. But I'm looking for a way to make the remote program stop without having to resort to a pseudo-terminal and specify extra options in the `ssh` call.

Comment: If this is tied to the host used, you can get a PTY without specifying `-t` in the commandline by configuring `RequestTTY` in `ssh_config`. Or you can use a shell function or script file to shadow `ssh` and add/alter options as desired.

Comment: If the reason you don't want a tty is because it mangles binary data and you need to transfer binary data then please check this: [*`ssh` with separate stdin, stdout, stderr AND tty*](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/653431/108618).

Comment: Related: [How to terminate remotely called "tail -f" when connection is closed?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/133951)

Answer (score 0):

I came up with a partial solution for certain cases.

The idea is this: When `ssh` gets killed on the client, whatever program was being run by the command on `server` loses its parent process and gets assigned `init` as its parent process.

So if you're able to edit the program that's running on `server` to continuously check the parent PID, then you'll notice once it switches to 1 and therefore `ssh` on the client must have been terminated.

```
cat <<-"EOF" | ssh user@server sh
while :; do
sleep 1
ppid="$(ps -p "$$" -o ppid= | tr -d "[:blank:]")"
[ "$ppid" = 1 ] && break
done
EOF
```

Comment: Or see if reading stdin gives EOF or writing stdout gives SIGPIPE (or if ignored EPIPE); _many_ programs do one or both of these automatically, but not `sleep`.